# Autocorrelation function of a stochastic process with independent variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a stochastic process. If $x_i$ and $x_j$ with ($i \neq j$) are independent $\forall i, j \in \mathbb N$. Suppose that each $x_l$, where $l$ is odd, follow the same distribution (say $f_l$). Likewise, each $x_m$, where $m$ is even, follow the same distribution (say $f_m$). Is the autocorrelation function of the process always equal to 0?

I think that it should be always equal to zero, but I'm not completely sure of the case in which we compute the correlation of two variables $x_a$ and $x_b$ when $a$ and $b$ are both odd or even because the variables have the same distribution in that case.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Since $x_i$ and $x_j$ for $i\neq j$ are independent, if all your distributions are mean zero, the autocorrelation of your process is zero (except on the diagonal)